# Learning Android application development

Tags: java, android

How long would it take to learn making an app with Android? Not a crap app but something useful etc.

I know Java up to databases and making a GUI and splash screens etc. 
But I have never made games or animations in Java.

Then I learned JavaScript and canvas and have made games and applications.

Based on this how long would it take as I would be willing to learn it as we will be thought apps in college next semester and would I know enough Java?

Comment: Depends on how quickly you learn. This can't be answered reasonably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learning Android development basics would not take too long if you have a good grasp of OOP concepts in Java. The official resources provided by [Official Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/) is good enough for you to walk through and start developing.

After all, learning on how to program is all about understanding the concept, not memorizing every existing syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will start learning it just after I finish my current html5 project and have it ready to port.

Comment: You're welcome. Have a successful life.